# Nome de exibição alterado em algumas comunidades Stack Exchange sem consentimento

Tags: suporte, bug, perfil

Ao fazer a alteração do meu perfil hoje no SOPT, percebi que em outros sites do Stack Exchange, ficaram divergentes, aparecendo meu nome como *user3722111*, e não replicando o restante das informações.

isso seria uma falha? Ou o meu entendimento do botão: <kbd>Salvar e copiar as mudanças para todas as comunidades Stack Exchange</kbd>
no perfil, está errada?

---

**Edit:**
Nos sites abaixo, meu perfil aparece alterado:
https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/76341/user3722111?tab=profile
https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/54829/user3722111?tab=profile
https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/users/618/user3722111?tab=profile

Aparece que eu alterei o nome:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gG8q.jpg
Mas eu não alterei.

Answer (score 3):

Fiz o teste aqui e funcionou na hora, editei no SOpt e cliquei em <kbd>Salvar e copiar as mudanças para todas as comunidades Stack Exchange</kbd>

- SOen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlFn8.png
- meta.stackexchange: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLZaz.png
- Stackapps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKzJ5.png

Adicionei no final da frase `em PHP`.

**O único site** que não atualiza sozinho é este http://stackexchange.com/users/1647724/guilherme-nascimento, tem que clicar no link *[Update profile info]*

É provável que seja um cache interno do servidor, ou seja alguma confusão sua.

Comment: vou testar novamente

Comment: testei e a parte de edição do "Sobre mim" está replicando, mas agora acredito que o problema seja outro, meu nome foi alterado sem meu consentimento em outros sites, (editei a pergunta).

Comment: @David pode ter ocorrido em alguma "manutenção" ou falha do sistema, vou deixar para alguém da equipe responder pois isto vai muito além, só a Staff poderá dizer ao certo

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme. Será que deleto a pergunta e crio outra?

Comment: @David deixa aberta, só muda o titulo pra deixar mais evidente o problema ;)